# Why after passing canvas.getWidth() method to x coordinate the object is not being drawn?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I created a class named MyButton, to help me draw rect and doing some actions when its beeing pressed, but when Im passing to the x and y coordinates values, using math on the canvas.getWidth() and canvas.getHeight() method, the button is not being drawn:

This is the methoed to set the coordinates and the height and width of the button:

```
public void setVars(float x, float y, float width, float height)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
```

this is what I tried and didnt work:

```
this.buttonHint.setVars((float)0, (float)(canvas.getHeight() - canvas.getHeight()/20), (float)(canvas.getWidth()/2), (float)(canvas.getHeight()/20));
this.buttonSuperHint.setVars((float)(canvas.getWidth()/2), (float)(canvas.getHeight() - canvas.getHeight()/20), (float)(canvas.getWidth()/2), (float)(canvas.getHeight()/20));
```

but when I try this, it works:

```
    this.buttonHint.setVars((float)0, (float)(20), (float)(canvas.getWidth()/2), (float)(canvas.getHeight()/20));
    this.buttonSuperHint.setVars((float)(20), (float)(20), (float)(canvas.getWidth()/2), (float)(canvas.getHeight()/20));
```

Answer (score 0):

probably the width/height of the canvas you are calling is still 0 at that time. add some listeners of the width/height of the canvas and make sure it has it's height/width set other than 0, then try calling that button attributes.

Comment: I checked it but the values are not 0. I used the drawText method in order to find out, besides, i pass the height and width of the rect using the canvas.getWidth and it is working